# react-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation') with react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just started developing in react native and i'm experiencing an error, i've included Drawer navigation in my app and when its tapped in the content view, the side menu bar opens up but when its tapped on there

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
                 style={{padding:10}}>
             <Icon  size={27} name='ios-menu' color='#fff' />
             </TouchableOpacity>
```

it throws an error.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation')
```

below is my script

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Container, 
        Header, 
        Content, 
        List, 
        ListItem, 
        Left, 
        Icon, 
        Body,
        Title,
        Right} from 'native-base';

class HomeScreen extends Component{


    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#28608c',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        headerLeft:(
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
             style={{padding:10}}>
         <Icon  size={27} name='ios-menu' color='#fff' />
         </TouchableOpacity>

        ),
        headerRight:(
          <TouchableOpacity style={{padding:10}}>
           <Icon size={27}  name='search' color='#fff' />
          </TouchableOpacity>

        )
      };
  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
        <Text onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}>HomeScreen</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Don't the variable is called navigationOptions instead of options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the react-navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title):

> It might be tempting to try to use `this.props` inside of `navigationOptions`, but because it is a static property of the component, `this` does not refer to an instance of the component and therefore no props are available. Instead, if we make `navigationOptions` a function then React Navigation will call it with an object containing `{ navigation, navigationOptions, screenProps }`

So, you need to change your `navigationOptions` to look like the following:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        // snip...

        headerLeft:(
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} // remove "this.props" here
             style={{padding:10}}>
             <Icon  size={27} name='ios-menu' color='#fff' />
         </TouchableOpacity>
        ),

        // snip...
      };
  };
```